# How to deal with column which save AMOUNT value with the replication

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We are using SQL Server 2008 SP 2, and there is a replication between 6 sites

The problem is:

we save amount values in a column (ex: 500$), which maybe changed in two sites at the same time, then if the replication is down at that time, so we have two different values in both sites, and if I use recent updated or publisher as a winner I will get wrong amount value

Are there any replication strategies to merge the two values?

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange about your question.  If you use transactional replication (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx)) on a *transactional* database, then this will not happen.

The problem is that your database is not designed correctly.  You are allowing "incremental" changes to go into fields, without storing the increments (transactions).  Your question is a bit ambiguous, because you don't explain what should really be happening.  Why isn't the most recent value sufficient?

You should be storing database changes as transactions:

- Starting value:  $500
- Transaction 1:  Add $100
- Transaction 2:  Subtract $200

Instead of as absolute values:

- Starting value:  $500
- Transaction 1:  Change value to $600
- Transaction 2:  Change value to $400

In the first case, you can apply the transaction in either order to catch up.  In the second case, you will end up applying only one of them.

Summary values, such as balance, should be derived from the transactions, perhaps using triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately its not my design i use this DB as it is, and the DB designed to save the final balance (absolute value), so the case maybe when the replication down, if the value was 500, so at site 1 the value changed to 400 (deduct 100) and at site 2 the value changed to 300 (deduct 200), so i need the final balance to be 200 (deduct 100 + 200), is there any way to do that, thx